# Try is working but Catch not working in Javascript function as below mentioned

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

In below function Catch is not working. unable to get the error message.

```js
function reverseString(s) {
  var ary = s.split("");
  ary.reverse();
  try {
    console.log(ary.join(""));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
reverseString(1234);
```

Comment: `in below function` There is no "below function" here...

Comment: [catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) will only run if `console.log(ary.join(""));` fails, which it won't.

Comment: You have an error because you try to use a string method .split() on a number without casting it. And you don't catch that error because it's outside your try block.

Comment: this function does not reach the catch block!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `s` is a `string` before you start doing your calculations.

Either convert `s` to a `string`:

```js
function reverseString(s) {
  var ary = String(s).split("");
  ary.reverse();
  try {
    console.log(ary.join(""));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
reverseString(1234);
```

Or throw a custom error if `s` is not a string:

```js
function reverseString(s) {
  if (typeof s !== "string") throw Error("s is not a string");
  // or
  // if (typeof s.split !== "function") throw Error("split is not supported");
  var ary = s.split("");
  ary.reverse();
  try {
    console.log(ary.join(""));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
try {
  reverseString(1234);
} catch (err) {
  console.log("Error: " + (err && err.message));
}
try {
  reverseString("1234");
} catch (err) {
  console.log("Error: " + (err && err.message));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just bring `var ary = s.split("");` as part of the `try` statement and use `console.error` in your catch.

```js
function reverseString(s) {
  try {
  var ary = s.split("");
  ary.reverse();
  console.log(ary.join(""));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
reverseString(1234);
```

Comment: you can take care of your whole statement easily